# A simple recipe for conditional webservice activity in Action.async in a play controller

Tags: web-services, scala, asynchronous, playframework

I am trying to use scala and playframework as a front-end to a database server which has a RESTful HTTP API.

My problem is the the logic of the controller requires a lookup to the database, then a decision and then 2 updates to the database.  I am trapped in aync future hell at the moment and can't see my way out.

Here is a psuedo-code outline of what I am trying to do:

```
def myMethod = Action.async {
    if (A exists in DB) {
                get A.value from the db
                if (A.value == x) {
                       update A.value
                       insert B
                       if (success) Status(200)
                       else         Status(500)
                   }
                else Status(409)
        }
    else Status(404)        
}
```

Any advice or links to **current** tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What ORM are you working with?  How do you send parameters to the action (json/form-data...)? If all of it doesn't really matter, I can give you an example of something we did with Slick

Comment: It all doesn't (shouldn't) matter because each db access or event is simply a call to a web-service.

Comment: Consider using Play monadic actions: https://github.com/Kanaka-io/play-monadic-actions#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Composing Dependent Futures](https://tersesystems.com/2014/07/10/composing-dependent-futures/), which has a lot of good things to say as well as acknowledging the difficulties (especially when mixing `Future` and `Option`).

Here's some (rough) code which sort-of simulates what you describe. As there often is in Scala there are many ways to do it (`map`, `flatMap`, `for` comprehensions etc) and some things appear more comprehensible than others.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
// Future.successful looks nicer IMO when aliased
import scala.concurrent.Future.{successful => immediate}

// A mock item
case class Thing(value: Int)

// A mock service, note that get returns an option
// to cover the not-existing case
object Service {
  def get(id: Int): Future[Option[Thing]] = ???
  def update(id: Int, item: Thing): Future[Thing] = ???
  def create(item: Thing): Future[Thing] = ???
}

def myMethod(id: Int) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  val x = 666 // um, or whatever?

  Service.get(id).flatMap {
    case Some(thing) if thing.value == x =>
      (for {
        // NB: We don't care about the results so using _ here
        _ <- Service.update(x, Thing(1001))
        _ <- Service.create(Thing(1002))
      } yield Ok) recover {
        // Handle the error case from one of the futures
        case e => InternalServerError(e.getMessage)
      }
    case Some(thing) => immediate(Conflict(thing.toString))
    case None => immediate(NotFound)
  }
}
```

A few things to note:

- I'm mixing `flatMap` and a `for` comprehension, which may be questionable style but I think it looks better this way
- I've replaced you `Status(x)` with the named alternatives
- Since we only do asynchronous work in one case, the other cases return a `Future.successful` (aliased to `immediate`), which is like a no-op future

Comment: Thanks for this.  It helps my learning a lot!  On review I could accommodate both the update and create in a single transaction (in Orientdb)  so I just used a second .flatMap.  The main thing I learnt was to set up db functions that return exactly what you need (ie `Future[Option[T]]`) because it makes everything easier to control and debug.